# How to bind the fragment to the activity?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

1. I customize a subclass of the fragmentpageradapter class（The value of the incoming position returns a fragment class）
2. Customize a fragment subclass
3. Find the viewpager control and instantiate a fragmentpageradapter class (passed to fragmentManager) in mainactivity and connect viewpager to adapter

Is that fragment already bound to the activity, in what form? Is it through fragmentManager? Still?

（I only know that you can add fragments in activity through fragment transactions)

Comment: Yes, it's by the FragmentManager. Is that your only question?

Comment: activity ——＞ fragmentPagerAdapter ——＞ fragmentManager ——＞ fragment ?    Don't have to keep atomicity through transactions?